# Cannot build after removing Google Play service?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I used Google Play Analytics and Google GCM in my projects.

Now I want to remove all of them. So I delete google-services.json file, remove dependencies from gradle files. But it still generates this meta data in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I cannot build because **google_play_services_version is not found**.

Did I miss something?

Comment: post your build.grdle

Comment: I think you forget to remove dependencies from top level `build.gradle` file . Remove this line `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` if found.

Comment: Remove also the apply plugin